# Lua function constantly returning false out of SQL function

Tags: lua, fivem

I have this code

```
function IsAuthorized(xPlayer, doorID, locked, usedLockpick)
    local jobName, grade = {}, {}
    jobName[1] = xPlayer.job.name
    grade[1] = xPlayer.job.grade
    if xPlayer.job2 then
        jobName[2] = xPlayer.job2.name
        grade[2] = xPlayer.job2.grade
    end
    local canOpen = false


    if doorID.lockpick and usedLockpick then
        count = xPlayer.getInventoryItem('lockpick').count
        if count and count >= 1 then canOpen = true end
    end

    if not canOpen and doorID.authorizedJobs then
        for job,rank in pairs(doorID.authorizedJobs) do
            if (job == jobName[1] and rank <= grade[1]) or (jobName[2] and job == jobName[2] and rank <= grade[2]) then
                canOpen = true
                if canOpen then break end
            end
        end
    end


    if not canOpen and doorID.items then
        local count
        for k,v in pairs(doorID.items) do
            count = xPlayer.getInventoryItem(v).count
            if count and count >= 1 then
                canOpen = true
                local consumables = { ['ticket']=1 }
                if locked and consumables[v] then
                    xPlayer.removeInventoryItem(v, 1)
                end
                break
            end
        end
        if not count or count < 1 then canOpen = false end
    end

    if not canOpen then
        local group = xPlayer.getGroup()
        if group == 'management' or group == 'owner' then
            print(group..' '..xPlayer.getName()..' was authorised to use a door')
            canOpen = true
        end
        if doorID.authorizedgang then
            print(xPlayer.identifier .. " | " .. doorID.authorizedgang)
            MySQL.Async.fetchSingle('SELECT * FROM users WHERE identifier = ? AND gang = ?', {xPlayer.identifier, doorID.authorizedgang}, function(foundplayer)
                if foundplayer then
                    print("found")
                    canOpen = true
                    print(canOpen)
                end
----------------------------canopen returns true until here
            end)
        end
    end


    print(canOpen)
    return canOpen
end
```

Essentially what is does is return a true or false value based on the if statements. I did not write this script myself, I simply added on. The code that I added to this function is

```
if doorID.authorizedgang then
            print(xPlayer.identifier .. " | " .. doorID.authorizedgang)
            MySQL.Async.fetchSingle('SELECT * FROM users WHERE identifier = ? AND gang = ?', {xPlayer.identifier, doorID.authorizedgang}, function(foundplayer)
                if foundplayer then
                    print("found")
                    canOpen = true
                    print(canOpen)
                end
----------------------------canopen returns true until here
            end)
        end
```

This code essentially makes a database call to check if it'll find a player with X identifier and Y gang, and this actually does work because it prints out "found" and canOpen returns true until the line that I marked, after this it returns false at the bottom of the function.

I've been trying other ways to get the data but ultimately I need the SQL DB call for this and im not sure why the variable isnt setting when in fact the database returns found. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you aware that those are async function calls? You probably return the `canOpen` value (which is `false`) and then eventually set it to `true` in your callback. Effectively ignoring it. If you print e.g. `exit` at the end of the outer function, does it happen after `found`?

Comment: no effectively the very last print always comes out false but other true

Comment: I know, but what's about the order? Are you sure the callback is called before the function terminated?

Comment: Ah, I've tried placing it at the very start of the function, in the middle, etc. I've played with the idea of making it its own function as well but to no luck with any of it

Comment: You are missing the point of async here. You simply do not have the result until at some point in the future, independent on where you place it and definitely outside your functions. You can either look for synchronous solutions, which are not recommended but probably the quickest solution, or rewrite your code to also work async, that means, continues when the callback is called. Just remember that an synchronous calls halts the script, and depending where it runs this may be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I really appreciate this. Can you suggest anywhere that could help me better understand?